# Simple Example - Argo and Swift 2

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to figure out [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo), but I'm struggling even with a simple example.  How would you decode the following sample Luke Skywalker JSON using Argo in Swift 2:

http://swapi.co/api/people/1/

Here is one thing I tried.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Argo
import Curry

struct SWPerson {
    var name: String
    var height: Int
}

extension SWPerson: Decodable {
    static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<SWPerson> {
    return curry(SWPerson.init) // Error here
        <^> j <| "name"
        <*> j <| "height"
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://swapi.co/api/people/1/").responseJSON { response in

            if let j = response.result.value {
                let luke: SWPerson? = decode(j)
                print(luke?.name)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The result of `print(luke?.name)` is `nil`.  I was hoping for `Luke Skywalker`.

Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example and the error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the JSON from the api you're trying to parse is using a string for the `height` property. Since you've typed that property on your model as an `Int` it will fail to parse. You could change that property to a `String` or create a `String -> Int?` function. I think it could be as simple as `<*> (j <| "height" >>- { .fromOptional(Int($0)) })`.

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at the Argo readme "TL;DR" example suggests only the first parameter gets the `<^>` construct; all others seem to get `<*>`. So your problem line may need to read:

```
return curry(SWPerson.init) 
  <^> j <| "name"
  <*> j <| "height"
```

Admittedly I've never used Argo or Curry, so I may be wrong or there may be additional problems beyond this one.

Comment: In fact, a closer look at the docs (specifically: https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/blob/master/Documentation/Basic-Usage.md under "Currying User.init") backs up my suspicion.

Comment: That allows things to build, but my print(luke?.name) prints nil.  So it is not parsing the JSON correctly.

Comment: Okay, so have you set a breakpoint in your request response closure and stepped through to inspect in the debugger? What do you find?

Comment: Yes.  j is being set fine (i.e. it contains a dictionary with all the key value pairs).  The return curry isn't working right though because luke remains nil.

Comment: Check out the Decoding Basics section of the link I procided in my comment and rewrite your decode function to preserve the failure info. Inspect the failure and let us know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I just don't get it.  I guess I don't understand curry.

Comment: I don't think it's the use of the Curry code; I think Argo is probably failing to parse the JSON but, per the documentation section I cited most recently, your code ( `let luke: SWPerson? = decode(j)` ) is ignoring any possible error information. If you follow its "//preserve error info" example: `let decodedLuke: Decoded<SWPerson> = decode(j)` instead, you can break just after that line and inspect `decodedLuke` (which will contain either a `Decoded<SWPerson>` or some kind of error info you can inspect. Try that. I'll bet there'll be an error that'll make you kick yourself. :-)

Comment: All that said, I'm not a big fan of "magical" syntactic sugar such as the Curry code that Argo includes. It may be more compact looking but it's too "cute" and makes the code harder to understand and debug unless you fully understand how it works.

Comment: Right you are!  It was returning height as a string and I had it set as an Int.  I think that is supposed to be a feature of Argo.  Thanks again for your help!  I think I'm going to skip using Argo.  The actual JSON I'll be getting for my project is controlled by me so I don't have to worry about things changing.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Be sure that you import in your **Podfile** the following packages:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'argoTest' do
pod 'Argo'
pod 'Curry'
end
```

**Example 1. Parsing a struct.**
This is what we want to parse:

```
 [{
  "id": 34,
  "name": "Juan",
  "cars": []
  },{
  "id": 35,
  "name": "Paco",
  "cars": [{"year":2000,"brand":"citroen"}]
  },{
  "id": 36,
  "name": "Salvador",
  "cars": [{"year":2000,"brand":"peugeot"},{"year":2005,"brand":"renault"}]
  }]
```

Those are **the modeling structs**:

```
import Foundation

import Argo
import Curry

struct CarOwner {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let cars: [Car]?
}

extension CarOwner: Decodable {
    static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<CarOwner> {
        return curry(CarOwner.init)
            <^> j <| "id"
            <*> j <| "name"
            <*> j <|| "cars" // Use ? for parsing optional values
    }
}
```

and this one:

```
import Foundation

import Argo
import Curry

struct Car {
    let year: Int
    let brand: String
}

extension Car: Decodable {
    static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<Car> {
        return curry(Car.init)
            <^> j <| "year"
            <*> j <| "brand"

    }
}
```

For parsing:

```
let carOwners:Decoded<[CarOwner]> = decode(JSONFromFile("car_owners")!)
```

"car_owners" is the filename that contains the JSON.

Finally the helper functions for retrieving data from file are the following:

```
    import Foundation

func JSONFromFile(file: String) -> AnyObject? {
  return NSBundle(forClass: JSONFileReader.self).pathForResource(file, ofType: "json")
    .flatMap { NSData(contentsOfFile: $0) }
    .flatMap(JSONObjectWithData)
}

private func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData) -> AnyObject? {
  return try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
}

private class JSONFileReader { }
```

**Example 2. Parsing a class.** This is what we want to parse:

```
{
"year": 34,
"name": "Chispa"
}
```

This is the modeling class:
    import Foundation
    import Argo
    import Curry

```
class Pet{
    var year: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}

extension Pet : Decodable {
    typealias DecodedType = Pet

    static func decode(json: JSON) -> Decoded<Pet> {
        let pet = Pet()
        pet.year = (json <| "year").value!
        pet.name = (json <| "name").value!


        return .Success(pet)
    }
}
```

Finally for parsing:

```
let json: AnyObject = JSONFromFile("pets")!
let pet = Pet.decode(JSON(json))
```

"pets" is the filename that contains the json example.

You can find more examples in this [post](http://celeri.es/model-your-classes-with-argo-json-parser/) or visit [Argo official site](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo).